# Dataflow/Beam Templates, Productionization, Initialization, and ValueProviders

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dev-to-production

I have an Apache Beam job running on Google Cloud Dataflow, and as part of its initialization it needs to run some basic sanity/availability checks on services, pub/sub subscriptions, GCS blobs, etc. It's a streaming pipeline intended to run ad infinitum that processes hundreds of thousands of pub/sub messages.

Currently it needs a whole heap of required, variable parameters: which Google Cloud project it needs to run in, which bucket and directory prefix it's going to be storing files in, which pub/sub subscriptions it needs to read from, and so on. It does some work with these parameters before pipeline.run is called - validation, string splitting, and the like. In its current form in order to start a job we've been passing these parameters to to a PipelineOptionsFactory and issuing a new compile every single time, but it seems like there should be a better way. I've set up the parameters to be ValueProvider objects, but because they're being called outside of pipeline.run, Maven complains at compile time that ValueProvider.get() is being called outside of a runtime context (which, yes, it is.)

I've tried using NestedValueProviders as in the Google "[Creating Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#using-nestedvalueprovider)" document, but my IDE complains if I try to use NestedValueProvider.of to return a string as shown in the document. The only way I've been able to get NestedValueProviders to compile is as follows:

```
NestedValueProvider<String, String> pid = NestedValueProvider.of(
        pipelineOptions.getDataflowProjectId(),
        (SerializableFunction<String, String>) s -> s
);
```

(String pid = NestedValueProvider.of(...) results in the following error: "incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,X exist so that org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider conforms to java.lang.String")

I have the following in my pipelineOptions:

```
ValueProvider<String> getDataflowProjectId();
void setDataflowProjectId(ValueProvider<String> value);
```

Because of the volume of messages we're going to be processing, adding these checks at the front of the pipeline for every message that comes through isn't really practical; we'll hit daily account administrative limits on some of these calls pretty quickly.

Are templates the right approach for what I want to do? How do I go about actually productionizing this? Should (can?) I compile with maven into a jar, then just run the jar on a local dev/qa/prod box with my parameters and just not bother with ValueProviders at all? Or is it possible to provide a default to a ValueProvider and override it as part of the options passed to the template?

Any advice on how to proceed would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way templates are currently implemented there is no point to perform "post-template creation" but "pre-pipeline start" initialization/validation.

All of the existing validation executes during template creation. If the validation detects that there the values aren't available (due to being a ValueProvider) the validation is skipped.

In some cases it is possible to approximate validation by adding runtime checks either as part of initial splitting of a custom source or part of the `@Setup` method of a `DoFn`. In the latter case, the `@Setup` method will run once for each instance of the DoFn that is created. If the pipeline is Batch, after 4 failures for a specific instance it will fail the pipeline.

Another option for productionizing pipelines is to build the JAR that runs the pipeline, and have a production process that runs that JAR to initiate the pipeline.

Regarding the compile error you received -- the `NestedValueProvider` returns a `ValueProvider` -- it isn't possible to get a `String` out of that. You could, however, put the validation code into the `SerializableFunction` that is run within the `NestedValueProvider`. 
 Although I believe this will currently re-run the validation everytime the value is accessed, it wouldn't be unreasonable to have the `NestedValueProvider` cache the translated value.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm trying to go the jar route now, but I'm having a problem getting it to recognize the dataflow runner: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown 'runner' specified 'dataflow', supported pipeline runners [DirectRunner] There's another post on SO about this but the only answer specifies running during compile time, which isn't an option.

Comment: This sounds like a class path issue. Make sure the JAR containing the Dataflow runner is available at runtime.

Comment: I figured it out last week; the issue was one of dependency ordering in the pom. I moved dataflow-runner to the top of the dependency list and things started working. Thanks though!